# Accepting single byte special characters into the windows terminal (testing on cygwin)

Tags: c, utf-8, character-encoding, multibyte

I am testing a C program in the windows terminal.  I mocked up a quick example of the section I am having issues with.  The example is as follows:

```
 $ cat test.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main() {
         char var[6];
         scanf("%s", var);

         int i=0;
         while(var[i] != '\0') {
              printf("%x ", var[i]);
              i++;
         }
      return 0;
 }
```

When I use a string with "normal" characters such as "dd" the output is as expected "61 61" (hex 61 is the letter "d").  When I try to input special characters such as í (0xA1 or U+00ED) I get the following output:

```
 $ ./a.exe
 í
 ffffffc3 ffffffad
```

The UTF-8 codepage at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ shows that the backwards 'i' is in fact 0xc3ad.  How can I copy and paste this character as 0xA1, as I really want to input 0xA1 into the terminal, not 0xc3ad?  I am copy and pasting this from "charmap".  I even tried saving a text file in ANSI with the character and copying and pasting but I still get 0xc3ad.  Please assist me.

EDIT: Running the same on a mac also gives me c3ad.

Comment: There are no single-byte characters with codes over 127 in UTF-8. If you want to work with obsolete 8-bit encodings, you need to fiddle with your terminal settings and/or environment. On Windows, also probably account-wide settings. But you really should not do that in this current millennium. We now write programs that use whatever encoding the user wants for external representation (files, terminals), and either utf8 or wide character representation internally.

Comment: The reason is the program expects binary data.  For testing purposes I would like to be able to craft it using characters and copy + paste it then examine the output.  That is the reason why I want 0xA1 (the backwards exclamation) to be fed in as 0xA1 and not 0xc2ad

Comment: 0xA1 is a backwards exclamation in one particular encoding called ISO8859-1 and its variants. 0xA1 is not a backwards exclamation in ISO8859-2, ISO8859-3, ... Why do you select ISO8859-1 out of the sea of obsolete encodings?

Comment: Furthermore, if the program expects binary data, it is rather unwise to feed it characters copied and pasted to/from a terminal. The translation between characters you see and binary codes you get depends the language you set in your OS, and possibly also on the version of the OS, on the version of the terminal program and whatnot. Programs that interpret character input must take this stuff into account. Programs that expect binary data should not do that, and should not use `scanf` and friends, because `scanf` is similarly language- and environment-dependent.

Comment: Out of curiosity what do you mean by external vs internal representation?  Copy and paste your comments into an answer so I can up vote you

Comment: External rep is what is kept in files and sent over the net. Internal rep is kept in the main memory.